# Jinja syntax is not recognised by Pycharm pro

Tags: python, pycharm, jinja2

I have a html form and I want to parse the data entered by the user in another html file name login.html using flask.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
```

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=["POST"])
def receive_data():   
   if request.method == "POST":    
   return render_template("login.html", 
        name=request.form['name'],password=request.form['password'])
```

The HTML code doesn't recognise the path with `url_for` and gives me an unresolved warning. Why is it happening and what can I do to correct this?

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think there is a problem in the file path, because when I change to static file pathing like so `/login` it still doesn't work. I've edited the post can you have a look the file path please??

Comment: yes i did, it still shows a warning

Comment: the weirdest thing is that code actually works and does what I want it to do. It means that the file_path must be working, but I still get that working telling me that the file path doesn't work

Comment: actually the warning is really simple it says : Cannot resolve file ' . And by the way i'm using Pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Okay I solved the issue. The problem was that Pycharm could not recognise the jinja syntax so I went into Pycharm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Template languages and then changed the template language from none to Jinja2 on the roll-down menu. I'm on mac too so I don't know what is the path on windows, but i'm sure it wouldn't be very hard.
Also since I was confused in the beginning and thought the warning was given because of the way the url was written or something else I changed the title to something closer to what the issue really was.

Answer (score 0):

The function `url_for()` is used within a template to navigate a site through the route **function names** and not the possibly volatile URL strings. Calling `url_for()` with the route function name as it’s parameter is safer way to indicate routes within templates since URL strings can change based on a sites changing file structure.

The `url_for()` function needs to be called within expression delimiters `{{ }}` in order to be processed by the Jinja2 template engine. Keyword arguments can be added to the function call to pass variables to the Flask app route.:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('receive_data') }}" method="post">
```

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=["POST"])
def receive_data():   
   if request.method == "POST":    
   return render_template("login.html", 
        name=request.form['name'],password=request.form['password'])
```